# clearoption for optionset in crm business process flow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a business process flow
In one of its steps I have added an option set(sub category)

[image]

I am trying to clear the options in the optionset using the below code

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subcategory").removeOption(100000005)
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subcategory").clearOptions()
```

This removes the options for the optionset that is inside the form, but it is not removing for the same option set that is in the step of business process flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to added `header_process_` to the id.  So:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_new_subcategory").removeOption(100000005)
Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_new_subcategory").clearOptions()
```

[SDK reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_ControlsCollection)

Comment: thanks @polshgiant
I was reading the same SDK reference, didn't spot the header_process_ !